# With GitHub PRs, why do deleted empty files display 'Empty file.' instead of Deleted

Tags: github, pull-request

Using GitBash on Windows.

On GitHub, when viewing a PR, why do deleted empty files display 'Empty file.', whereas those with content state 'This file was deleted.'

Is this just a quirk?

I was very confused for a while because in a different repo, I faced the same issue with a very large PR but thought it was to do with a folder casing change, but it was a total red herring.

It feels pretty minor but it cost me quite a deal of time from thinking the file wasn't being deleted as part of the PR.

But if it's got a orange square minus sign box next to it, then consider that the source of truth?

It's nothing stranger, like some permission change, the Git Bash commands I used, or something?

[image: Pull Request delete file example]

Git Bash full example:

Create an empty file, commit and push:

```
touch test.md
git add test.md 
git commit -m "Empty File"
git push
```

Create a separate branch, remove the file, push:

```
git checkout -b TestDeleteBranch
git push -u origin TestDeleteBranch 
git rm test.md 
git commit -m "Test delete empty file"
git push
```

Add a file with *content* to main, merge it to branch:

```
git switch main
git touch testWithContent.md
touch testWithContent.md
echo "## content" >> testWithContent.md
git add testWithContent.md 
git commit -m "File with content"
git push
git switch TestDeleteBranch
git merge main
git push
```

Remove the file *with content* commit and push to branch:

```
git rm testWithContent.md
git commit -m "Test delete with content"
git push
```

Then create a PR to main via UI, compare the branch files vs main in image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github is just one of many websites and applications which are wrappers around Git and they can choose to display things how they like. Github wants to show you a diff of the contents, but there were no contents, so it says the file is empty. That it doesn't also say the file was deleted seems an oversight you could bring up with Github.

Here is how Git shows deleting a file with content using `git log -p`.

```
commit 7e182a6a84aad2db3d976bb3f3670dca02f2ad53 (HEAD -> TestDeleteBranch, origin/TestDeleteBranch)
Author: Michael G. Schwern <schwern@pobox.com>
Date:   Sat Nov 4 15:41:52 2023 -0700

    Test delete with content

diff --git a/testWithContent.md b/testWithContent.md
deleted file mode 100644
index 52dd624..0000000
--- a/testWithContent.md
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-## content
```

And a file without content.

```
commit 07aebea83e01920fea16799944cb0e942aad4066
Author: Michael G. Schwern <schwern@pobox.com>
Date:   Sat Nov 4 15:39:58 2023 -0700

    Test delete empty file

diff --git a/test.md b/test.md
deleted file mode 100644
index e69de29..0000000
```

In both cases it shows `deleted file mode 100644`.

Comment: Thanks, I found your point that it's just a wrapper over Git really good - it's better to understand and use the underlying technology over relying on a UI, to know definitively what's actually happening in your repository. 

So I know what I need to learn :)